# make html5 video go to first frame when it ends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have a simple video html5 tag, bound to an "ended" event:

```
$('#video').show().trigger("play").bind('ended', function () { 
//code
}
```

Since I'm "showing" and "hiding" this through a button click, I wanted to make it return to the first frame on that last function, so it would start from the beginning the next time it appears (right now it starts from the ending, and it causes a nasty flicker when it goes from the last to the first frame).

Is that possible with jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use something like

```
$('#video').show().trigger("play").bind('ended', function () { 
    this.currentTime = 0;
}
```

You can only set the currentTime if the loadedmetadata event has passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really did it. 

I just had to put a this.pause(); after the this.currentTime =0;, and worked like a charm on my code. Been busting my head for hours trying to solve this as the deadline was getting closer and closer, thanks again!!

Comment: @CCrawler, my code didn't work for you? Edit: Disregard. I misunderstood your question ;)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall No problem Marcus, thanks for your reply anyway!

Comment: @Niels

I just happen to find a problem with that code in Chrome and IE, they seem to ignore the this.currentTime = 0; part. I ran an alert('this.currentTime'); inside that function, and it returned numbers different from zero (1.67890 and the like). It worked perfectly in FFox; the value was properly set to zero, and the video behaved as expected.

Any idea why this might happen? You mentioned something about the loadedmetadata event, is there any way I could make sure that event has passed properly?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: loadedmetadata is when the video data is loaded, to get the maximum time and more data. If your video has played to the end, this data is already ready. If you want it to loop use `$("#video")[0].loop = true;`. But this [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974748(v=VS.85).aspx) tells you should be able to use currentTime. Or you can try `this.play(); this.pause();`

Answer (score 0):

This goes in the head:

```
<script>
function Reset() { document.getElementById('MyVideo').load(); }
</script>
```

This goes in the video tag:

```
<video ID="MyVideo" onended="Reset()" [plus your other parameters] >
```