# Set html5 video to specific frame

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set a html5 embedded video to the first frame of the video once it is out of view. I know I can call `play()` and `pause()` on the element to have it pause and play but can I set the video back to the first frame with javascript?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132890/make-html5-video-go-to-first-frame-when-it-ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can set it to a specific frame but you can set it to a specific second of the video. ex.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.currentTime = 5;
```

OR

if you mean you just want it to go back to the beginning once it ends you can just set it to loop via JS

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.loop = true;
```

OR by just adding the loop attribute to the video tag like

```
<video loop>
```

Comment: perfect. I will set this as correct as soon as I can